# "chrome --allow-file-access-from-files" only for one folder

Tags: google-chrome, security, chromium

I have this structure of bundled web app:

```
/dist
|
|- index.html
|- inline.js
|- main.js
|- polyfills.js
|- favicon.ico
|-assets
  |
  |-icons
    |
    |- add.svg
    |- arrow-down.svg
    |- start.svg
```

Due to various reasons I want to serve it via file:// protocol instead of hosting http server.

However, Chrome can't acces files that are located in /assets/ folder - all files that are in root (dist) folder work fine.

I found out that I can run chrome "--allow-file-access-from-files", however it's told to be dangerous, as it opens my whole file system to attacks.

**Is there any way to use "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag only for specific folder? Something like:**

```
$ chrome --allow-file-access-from-files ./assets/**
```

Comment: that would be a good feature to add on chrome I think +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

that would be a good feature to add on chrome I think
+1 from me